# Cannot extend GCMIntentService to modify notification view for native Android client [ Worklight 7.0 + Android ]

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to modify the view of push notification for Android.
The worklight implements the received notification into

```
com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService
```

And the library worklight-android.jar that integrates native Android with Worklight server and handles communications fires exception if the Manifest prepared with other class than

```
com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService
```

Need to modify the notification view to look like:

[Modified notification view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vymXf.png)

and trying to extend it and put the new reference into manifest as below:

```
<service android:name="com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.ClassExtendedGCMIntentService" />
```

The exception is as below:

```
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your manifest is not allowed to work with push. Android Manifest Error: Missing intent service in manifest: com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush.<init>(WLPush.java:185)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.getPush(WLClient.java:995)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at com.xxx.xxxxx.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:92)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
02-10 20:30:09.047 16652-16652/com.xxx.xxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Are you able to do it now ? I am facing same problem. could you please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

At this point , what you ask is not available in case of pure native Android applications incorporating Worklight/MobileFirst Android SDK. You can submit a Request for Enhancement (RFE) [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/).

In case of hybrid applications, your requirement can be achieved by extending the GCMIntentService class. More details can be found in the following links:

[Inbox Style notifications with IBM Worklight](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/inboxstyle_notifications_in_android?lang=en#s-android-gcm-intent-service)

[Multi Line Android Push Notifications with IBM MobileFirst](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/11/24/multi-line-gcm-push-notifications/)

Comment: This is not the problem, Extending the GCMIntentService is the solution yes but how to do it in a Native apps using the Worklight Native API ?. The solution you are providing is for the Hybrid apps.

Comment: Edited the answer to account for native Worklight API

Comment: Let me rephrase it, There are 2 types of applications to be integrated with Worklight server and uses it's APIs. 1- The Hybrid apps generated from the Worklight studio. 2- The pure native apps that you are generating normally without any auto generating from Worklight studio [ it's pure native not WebViews or core Cordova ]. those 2 types has 2 different implementation of PushNotification.

Comment: Right. 
1) To override default Push behaviour in hybrid application generated by Worklight studio, overriding the GCMIntentService class as described in the blog will help.
2) There is currently no option to do the same for pure native Android application incorporating Worklight/MobileFirst native Android SDK ( not webviews or core Cordova). You can submit a request for enhancement (RFE)